# Powerpivot change existing connection from excel to text

Tags: excel, connection, powerpivot

I'd like to change the connection of existing table in powerpivot. Currently the source is an Excel file on my hard drive, I'd like to change this to a text file.

From the research I've done I've found [this](https://dmoffat.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/how-you-can-change-to-another-connection-type-in-powerpivot/) blog which describes a solution to changing the type when the connection is a server, however I'm struggling to implement this solution with files that are stored on my pc

Hoping there's a simple answer here

Regards
Ria

Answer (score 0):

Ria, unfortunately, this isn't as of yet supported. When to try to change the type of file in *Existing Connections* dialogue window, you will get this error:

[image]

So the solution is to create a new connection using text file and reproduce all the work you have done. It's super stupid, but there is no other way at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: to add on to this, currently i am changing from a csv file to another but the problem is whenever i hit refresh it still gives me error.